# Some questions about implementing a preemptive scheduler in C: Context switching and execution time of the dispatcher

Tags: programming-practices, c, scheduling

I am trying to implement a preemptive scheduler in C, but I have some understanding problems:

When the scheduler is called by an interrupt, a context switch may occur. The context switch can only be programmed in assembler. In my C program a task is a function.
If the scheduler is called by an interrupt and a context switch occurs, then I cannot start a new task in the interrupt. In the interrupt I store the context of the current task (I'm not sure). But after the interrupt the program will return to the function. So where do I start a new task? Should I go back to the main loop in assembler after saving the context?

Comment: I think this requires going beyond pure C.

Comment: This question is really three questions in disguise (labelled accordingly). Maybe if you tried to split them into three separate posts people would be more willing to answer. Otherwise, I think this question is valid.

Comment: You're right, I changed it to one single question. I hope it's better this way.

Answer (score 4):

A preemptive scheduler can not be written entirely in C. The logic that is needed to switch between tasks must be written in assembly code, because you need low-level access to the processor's registers.

The way that a preemptive scheduler normally works is like this:

- Using a timer interrupt, the scheduler code is called every X microseconds
- When called

  - the scheduler checks which task has the highest priority to run
  - if that is the currently running task, then the scheduler returns
  - otherwise, the task-switching code is asked to alter the processor registers in such a way that the processor continues with the new task after the interrupt returns
  - the scheduler remembers which task is currently running
  - the scheduler returns from the interrupt

Comment: ... and then we get into the nitty-gritty, like round-robin or batch inside each priority, whether or not there's trickle-down of time-slices to avoid completely starving low-priority tasks, whether to suspend scheduling when there is only one task that can run at all ...

Comment: Why do you need low-level access to the processor's registers?  For performance reasons?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No, for manipulations that a normal program never would do, like swapping the call-stack underneath the scheduler's interrupt call from one task to another and swapping the register content that isn't automatically saved when entering an interrupt.